# Informatica data filter dealing with dates

Tags: informatica, data-synchronization

I was trying to setup an informatica task which delete records older than 1 year, eventually came up with filter like

```
 Date != last_n_days:365
```

However this filter does not cater the count of extra day of leap years. The  [official date literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) provided are not sufficient to distinguish the condition. Is there any recommended workaround for this?